# A good starting point for development Windows utilities interfacing with OS

Tags: c#, windows, utilities

I would like you to give me some good resources regarding Windows development of applications that integrates with OS like Application managers, Docks, Task-bar\System tray etc.

Resources like how to interact with particular subsystems are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is information on writing shell extensions. Generally it is not recommended that you write shell extensions in .NET though the landscape might be much better now with Framework 4.0 supporting side by side loading of the framework.

Searching with Bing/Google for `shell extension c#` will yield a number of results that might be relevant.

As for the docking part of your question, the most reliable way would be to register your application as an Application Desktop Toolbar (AppBar), here is a Code Project article on doing this with C#, it should be a fair starting point. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AppBar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It appears much of what you would like to know about involves using the Windows API. Its documentation might give you a start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383749(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: -1 Bad advice. Don't start with the reference material. By all means turn to it along the way, but it's a poor guide.